# The Firebase database subscription is not closed after the change reference

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

In my firebase app, there will be load more button and when user click it, it is expected to load more content. I used a listener for that but i can't closed after more content loaded. For example when user click 'load more' button, there would be one more subscription and old subscriptions will be triggered too.

```
export class PostComponent {
  private sub: Subscription;
  private counter = 50;
  constructor(private afm: AngularFireDatabase) {}
  loadPosts() {
    this.sub = this.afm.list("posts", { query: { limitToFirst: this.counter } })
      .subscribe((posts: any[]) => this.posts = posts);
  }

  loadMore() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
    this.counter += 50;
    this.loadPosts();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to unsubscribe right after the load, i.e, inside the subscribe callback.

Try this

```
loadPosts() {
  this.sub = this.afm.list("posts", { query: { limitToFirst: this.counter}})
     .subscribe((posts: any[]) => {
         this.posts = posts;
         this.sub.unsubscribe();
      });
}
```

Comment: After we did this, it would be like once listener. It won't trigger when changes occur. Exactly i want to close subscription after user click 'load more' button.